# How to avoid the "This message may not have been sent by" warning when sending email using Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have a python GAE app that sends emails like in the [example](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) using the address of a registered administrator for the application as the "sender" address. When an email arrives from such an API call, here's a pic of [the attached warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntcud.png).

> This message may not have been sent by: EmergencyButtonApp@gmail.com 
>   [Learn more](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=185812)  Report phishing

Am I doing something wrong? None of the 3 options mentioned in the "Learn More" link are relevant I believe: the sender is a gmail address so the "SPF and DKIM authentication" solution isn't relevant, I'm not sending to a mailing list and I'm not using SMTP (I think, though maybe GAE is...).

Comment: Are you using the SDK or a deployed app?

Comment: It's a deployed app on the Master/Slave (not HRD).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're seeing this in production, it's probably because you're claiming to be from a gmail address, but sending via App Engine. Use one of your app's email addresses as the sender (foo@yourapp.appspotmail.com) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use Google's SMTP servers... It's the best way to not be considered as a spammer.

Comment: You can't do this on App Engine.